# Using Microsoft Exchange Online to host emails but still allow piped emails in cPanel

Tags: email, exchange, exchangeonline

I want to use Microsoft Exchange Online to host my emails. I understand this involves changing  MX records to point to Microsoft's servers.

My issue is that in cPanel I have some piped email address that forward to PHP scripts which I cannot lose. Is there a way to host some emails addresses remotely while still keeping some addresses processed by my cPanel server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.  Depending on if you are talking about sending email FROM those addresses:

It's similar to allowing a lob app to send through an account on O365:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

OR if you are talking about mailboxes residing on the cPanel server:

If you are wanting to share SMTP namespaces with Exchange Online you can see my answer and comments here: [Office 365 routing of internal domain messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/563814/office-365-routing-of-internal-domain-messages)

You need to research these options and then if necessary ask a new question with details on what you tried if you run into issues.